# Applying inverse transposition in Eigen

Tags: c++, migration, permutation, eigen

I'm trying to migrate to Eigen 3.3 from  Eigen 3.2. But can not find a good way to apply an inverse transposition.

There is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110544/eigen-on-arm-cortex-m3-with-armcc), but the author did not provide a code and other details.

The following code worked fine with Eigen 3.2.9

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main(){
  using namespace Eigen;
  MatrixXd Q(MatrixXd::Random(3,3));
  VectorXi x(3);
  x << 0, 2, 1;
  Transpositions<Dynamic> P(x);
  Q = Q * P.inverse(); //or P.transpose()
  return 0;
}
```

But with Eigen 3.3.4 (in master in Eigen repository I also don't see any changes that may help, but I might fail to understand that templates) it fires the error:

```
error: ‘const class Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::TranspositionsBase<Eigen::Transpositions<-1> > >’ has no member named ‘derived’
       return Product<OtherDerived, Transpose, AliasFreeProduct>(matrix.derived(), trt.derived());
```

Method `inverse` itself exists, but I can not assign its result (in neither Eigen)

```
P.inverse(); // compiles
P = P.inverse(); // not compiles
```

The workaround seems to be simple:

```
for (Transpositions<Dynamic>::StorageIndex i = 0; i < P.size(); ++i)   Q.col(i).swap(Q.col(P(i)));
```

My questions:

1. What is the right way to use inverse transposition in Eigen 3.4?
2. Is there any lose of performance (for in-place case) in loop solution comparing to what
   Eigen does?

Comment: Workaround: `Q.transpose() = P*Q.transpose();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a shortcoming introduced in the 3.3 branch. It is now fixed in both the 3.3 and default branches.